# ODE $x'(t) = \sqrt{|x(t)^2 - 1|}$ is of class $C^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE :

$x'(t) = \sqrt{|x(t)^2 - 1|}$, $x(0) = a \in \mathbb{R}$.

We want to know if this ODE fulfils the conditions of the Cauchy-Lipschitz's theorem. If yes, is the maximal solution global (defined on $\mathbb{R}$) ?

The derivative of $\sqrt{|x(t)^2 - 1|}$ is $\dfrac{x^3-x}{\left|x^2-1\right|^\frac{3}{2}}$, which is not continous on all $\mathbb{R}$ (in particular for $x = \pm 1$). So, the conditions of Cauchy-Lipschitz's theorem are not fulfilled, is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\,f(x)=|x^2-1|^{1/2}\,$ is $C^1$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$. But it is not differentiable at $x=\pm 1$.

In fact, Lipschitz Condition is violated at $x=1$ and $x=-1$. Global uniqueness is thus not enjoyed by the IVPs of this ODE. For example,
$$
x'=|x^2-1|^{1/2}, \quad x(0)=1,
$$
possesses a constant solution as well as infinitely many non-constant ones.

Local uniqueness is nevertheless enjoyed by all IVPS, where $x(0)\ne \pm 1$.

On the other hand, every solution extends to the whole real line,  since the flux function $f(x)=|x^2-1|^{1/2}$ satisfies $|\,f(x)|\le |x|+1$.